# Show/Hide div send all data to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this show/hide div. And I am running into couple issues. I am using CodeIgniter by the way.

**First :** When I select real-estate the div shows. But if I select Service, the real-estate div won't hide.  (Service has no div).

**Second :**  If I select real-estate and fill out the form, and I change my mind and select  automobile and fill out the form then send to database, I get all the fields from real-estate and automobile into my database. Which is not what I want.

**Third :** Is there a different approach if I wanna add more categories and more divs show/hide?

```
<select id="catid_1" name="catid_1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="5">Real-Estate</option>
<option value="8">Automobile</option>
<option value="10">Service</option>
</select>
<!--Auto-->
<div id="8" class="forms">
 Energie :
 <select name="energy">
     <option></option>
     <option value="Gasoline">Gasoline</option>
     <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
     <option value="GPL">GPL</option>
     <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
     <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>

 </select><br />

 Transmission :
 <select name="tans">
 <option></option>
 <option value="Manuel">Manuel</option>
 <option value="Automatic">Automatic</option>
 </select><br />

 Miles :
 <input type="text" name="mile"/><br />
 Year :
 <input type="text" name="year"/><br />


</div>

<!--Realestate-->
<div id="5" class="forms">
   Room :
   <input type="text" name="room"/><br />
   Surface :
   <input type="text" name="surface"/><br />
</div>

<!--End Tech-->


$(function() {
    $(".forms").hide();
    $("#catid_1").change(function() {
    var e = $(this).val();
    if(e == '8' || e == '5') {
    $(".forms").hide().parent().find('#' + e).show().addClass('form-active');
    }
});

// Bind to the submit
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Parse the data only for the displayed div.
    var resolve_data = function() {
        var output = {};
        // Here you place the acceptable fields.
        $('.form-active input, .default input').each(function() {
            output[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
        return output;
    };

    // Submit the form here.
    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: resolve_data(),
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
        // Before sending, check the data.
        alert(settings.data);
      },
      complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        //called when complete
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //called when successful
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //called when there is an error
      }
    });
 });

 });
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle containing this code: http://jsfiddle.net/zf9BN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first**: `service` show/hide is not working because you're putting a conditional on the ID:

```
if(e == '8' || e == '5') { // <<-- remove this conditional
$(".forms").hide().parent().find('#' + e).show().addClass('form-active');
}
```

**second**: When you're doing your update, check the value of the drop down box and only update the fields that belong to that choice. Your form should be sending along the value of the option, so that's not to hard to do. For instance, if the `select` value is 5, only update the `room` and `surface` fields in your database. Don't try to clear the form when switching choices, it's safer to do this in the back end.

If you insist on doing it front end, put an actual form in there and `.reset()` it when changing options.

**third**: probably, but this seems OK no? Are you not happy with it?

http://jsfiddle.net/zf9BN/1/

Comment: One problem is solved. The problem is, I need to erase the data once the fields are filled out when I choose another option. EX: If I fill out real-estate and then choose automobile, real-estate data still there, and when submit all goes to DB

Comment: It's not real smart to do that front end only.. Your form will be unreliable even if you clear it. I can for instance open up the dev  console and populate all the fields even if you clear them... I've updated the answer.